# How to prompt the execution of a custom script after a task has been completed

Tags: command-line, apt, scripts, dpkg

I have created a script called `checkrest` and I have placed it with executable rights in the `/bin` directory. The script checks if a restart is required by an application, and if so, it checks which application(s). I find this rather useful as I otherwise have to do lots of manual work to figure out if anything on my system needs a restart.

I am having to run this manually at the moment, but I would find it much more useful if I could get it to run every time after I execute an APT command which makes changes to my system. Or after I execute a `dpkg` command which makes changes to my system. So for instance after installing, removing, or configuring any software I would like for it to automatically execute this little script I've created. So what's the best way of doing this? But I also wish to do this sort of thing with other custom made scripts, so how is this sort of thing generally done?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76294/hook-a-script-to-apt-get

Comment: muru has provided a very good link but that is `apt` specific..perhaps you should generalize your question so that the answers are kind of generic (not restricted to `apt`)..

Comment: @heemayl: Is that generalized enough? Or does it need more generalization? I so, let me know when you think needs editing, or edit it yourself. :)

Comment: I think its fair enough  :)

Comment: "how is this sort of thing generally done?" - write a wrapper script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a lazy man's script to get the job done (considering only one instance of process is running):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while [ -h /proc/"$(pgrep apt-get)"/exe ]; do
    sleep 10
done
echo "DONE"
```

Replace `echo "DONE"` with what you want to do next. You can run it as a `cron` job.

Every process has a directory in `/proc` assigned with their PID, the full path to executable is symlinked as `exe` inside that directory. Here we are checking if that file exists and is a symlink.

We could use `[ -d /proc/PID ]` but that would give us wrong result as when the value of `PID` is null it will become `[ -d /proc ]` which always exists, so the script will run indefinitely.